# obtaining a reference to IHTMLCanvasElement

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, dom, mshtml

How Can I get a DOM reference to the canvas Handle. I'm using Delphi, IE11 and the corresponding MSMHTML Type library,I suspected it's along the lines of

```
canvasHandle := (HTMLDoc3.getElementById('canvas') as IHTMLCanvasElement);
```

the Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas">
  ....
</canvas>
```

however this throws an exception 'Interface not supported'

Comment: Are you using a `TWebBrowser` control to obtain `HTMLDoc3`? if yes, then I guess you need to specify rendering/browser mode for it. default rendering mode is IE7. look for [`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`](http://www.google.com/search?q=FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION+IE11), or add a `"meta http-equiv-'X-UA-Compatible' content= edge"` to the `<head>` block of a webpage to force Windows IE to use the latest standards.

Comment: Yes: I should have made that point clear, I am using the TWebBrowser control
however HTMLDoc3 works fine as I tested it on other tags without any problems

what looks promising is placing "meta http-equiv-'X-UA-Compatible' content= edge" to the <head> block of a webpage

Comment: Applying Kobik's suggestion of adding "Meta http-equivalent' did solve the problem, would accept if posted as an answer,

Comment: @kobik, ping :-) Mark, please use `@` before the user's name to notify us through comments. We don't need to do that since you're the owner of the post and so you're always notified. Thanks!

Comment: @TLama, Reply from "kobik": Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` control, by default uses IE7 standards/rendering mode.
You need to tell the control to use latest standards. 
There are a few ways of doing this.

Here are two of the ways known to me:

- Either you specify `FEATURE_<some feature>` for your application in the registry (.e.g. [`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`](http://www.google.com/search?q=FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION%20IE11) also a nice article [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)).
- Add a `"meta http-equiv-'X-UA-Compatible' content= edge"` to the `<head>` block of a webpage to force Windows IE to use the latest standards.
  This will enable your HTML5 functionality working without the need for registry tweaks.